# Error when creating new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting my first Ruby on Rails project and when I ran my `rails new (projectname)` command, I got the following error in command prompt.

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0
state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate failed
(https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.4.2.gem)

An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bunderler cannot
continue. Make sure that gem install 'gem install rake -v 10.4.2
succeeds' before bundling`
```

If I'm not mistaken, it looks like it cannot download the Ruby gem for "rake" because the SSL certificate at the URL is not trusted.  Is there a way to install without SSL or to make the SSL cert a trusted certificate?

If I'm incorrect in my assumption about the error, can someone point me in the right direction to fix this please?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yeah, that has happened sometimes with some versions of rubygems and some OSs, and it's annoying. First thing to do, try making sure you have the latest version of rubygems, run `gem update --system`. If that doesn't work, or doesn't solve your problem, let us know what OS you are on and what version of rubygems you have (`gem --version`)

Comment: @jrochkind I tried running `gem update --system` and I received the following error:

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RmoteFetcher::FetchError)
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

I ran `gem --version` as suggested, and it's version 2.2.2.  My operating system is 64-bit Windows 8.1.

Comment: @mike84 can you give us the link of rubygems in the Gemfile

Comment: @mike84 also check this http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

Comment: @mike84 It is SSL certificate problem. There is an excellent writeup by Daniel Kehoe on [OpenSSL Errors and Rails – Certificate Verify Failed](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html). This might help in resolving your issue. If it still doesn't work, do checkout the steps given in the first comment on the article.